# Temporarily Disabling trigger in Sql Server using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have created the below method in c# for disabling trigger temporarily

```
public static void DisableTriggers<TEntity>(this Table<TEntity> table) where TEntity : class
    {
        ArgumentValidation.CheckForNullReference(table, "table");

        string sql = string.Format("IF object_id('tempdb..#DISABLETRIGGER_ReviewEDoc') IS NULL BEGIN create table tempdb..#DISABLETRIGGER_ReviewEDoc (col int) END", table.GetTriggerDisabledTempTableName());

        table.Context.ExecuteCommandLogErrors(sql);
    }
```

And checking for the same temp table in SQL update trigger like below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DISABLETRIGGER_ReviewEDoc') IS NULL
BEGIN
-- SKIP logic written here
END
```

The problem is it doesn't seems to work, the check is always returning null.

Thanks in advance for you Ideas/Suggestions

Comment: If you have to disable triggers on the fly then there is something wrong with your model.  My suggestion is to find a way to remove the triggers since they are almost always the wrong choice.

Comment: What are you trying to do and where is the relevant code? Your code doesn't use LINQ anywhere. There is no code that creates or disables triggers either - just code that creates a temporary table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The method "DisableTriggers" is actually a extension  method create over the Linq to sql context. Also I am not disabling the triggers from code instead using a trick to temporarily disable it

Comment: It's impossible to help unless you provide the relevant code. In any case, whatever you are trying to do can probably be done with far simpler methods. You shouldn't have to reverse engineer tempdb, or add triggers to temporary tables to do whatever it is you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the "real" name of temporary objects are different than you use in script.

**EDIT:**
If you run this script:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempdb.sys.objects
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tempdb.sys.objects ORDER BY create_date DESC

CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable ( ID int )
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tempdb.sys.objects ORDER BY create_date DESC
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempdb.sys.objects

DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempdb.sys.objects
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tempdb.sys.objects ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

you will see, what objects are in Temp DB. The `name` column is real name of the database object (i.e. table).

The name `#MyTempTable` is translated by sql server execution engine to correct name. In my case there is object named `#MyTempTable________________________________________________________________________________________________________00000000027C`.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the difference in name? Because, when I created the same temp table from same name from SSMS it seems to be working fine